# How to display pdf from db in iframe

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, mysql

I made a file upload system where the files when uploaded is stored in a db. now i have created an iframe so that i can view the files inside it. currently i have set the iframe to display a file(not inside db) but when i`m unable to set the iframe to display the files from the db. I've done a lot of research over this but hit a road block after road block, so I really hope your help in this, many thanks!
[image: WHEN THE OPEN PDF BUTTON IS CLICKED THE PDF MUST OPEN IN THE IFRAME]

```
    <html>
<title>File|Mgr</title>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <meta name="description" content="">
<link href="globe.png" rel="shortcut icon">
<?php
date_default_timezone_set("Asia/Calcutta");
//echo date_default_timezone_get();
?>


<?php
   $conn = mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","stu_supervision");
 session_start();
// Check connection
if (mysqli_connect_errno())
  {
  echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
  }

if(isset($_POST['submit'])!="")
{
  $name=$_FILES['photo']['name'];
  $size=$_FILES['photo']['size'];
  $type=$_FILES['photo']['type'];
  $temp=$_FILES['photo']['tmp_name'];
  $date = date('Y-m-d H:i:s');
  //$caption1=$_POST['caption'];
 // $link=$_POST['link'];
  $file_error = $_FILES['photo']['error'];


    $file_ext = explode('.', $name);
    $file_ext = strtolower(end($file_ext));

    //$allowed  = array('jpg', 'jpeg');
    $allowed  = array('pdf');

    if(in_array($file_ext, $allowed))
    {
        if($file_error === 0)
        {
             if(file_exists('par_files/' . $name))
                {
                   // die('<script type="text/javascript">alert("File with that name already exists.");location.replace("index.php")</script>');   

                   die('<script type="text/javascript">alert("File with that name already exists.");location.replace("par_upload.php")</script>');   
                }


            //if($size <= 2097152) {




    //--------WHEN UPLOADING FILE, A UNIQUE ID IS GENERATED IN FILES FOLDER THRU 1ST METHOD -------------------
               /// $file_name_new = uniqid('', true) . '.' . $file_ext; 
              //  $file_destination = 'files/' . $file_name_new;  
                $file_destination = 'par_files/'.$name ;
                move_uploaded_file($temp, $file_destination);

                $query=mysqli_query($conn,"INSERT INTO upload (name,date,par_id) VALUES ('$name','$date','".$_SESSION['par_id']."')");


                if($query){
               // header("location:index.php");
                    header("location:par_upload.php");
                }
                else{
                die(mysql_error());
                }
    }

        }
     else
      { 
        echo '<script language="javascript">';
        echo 'alert(" SORRY! YOU ARE ONLY ABLE TO UPLOAD PDF FILES")';
        echo '</script>';
      }
}

?>





<html>
<body>

<link href="css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/DT_bootstrap.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/font-awesome.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="font-awesome/css/font-awesome.min.css"/>
</head>
<script src="js/jquery.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="js/bootstrap.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" language="javascript" src="js/jquery.dataTables.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" language="javascript" src="js/DT_bootstrap.js"></script>
<?php include('dbcon.php'); ?>
<style>
.table tr th{

    border:#eee 1px solid;

    position:relative;
    #font-family:"Times New Roman", Times, serif;
    font-size:12px;
    text-transform:uppercase;
    }
    table tr td{

    border:#eee 1px solid;
    color:#000;
    position:relative;
    #font-family:"Times New Roman", Times, serif;
    font-size:12px;

    text-transform:uppercase;
    }

#wb_Form1
{
   background-color: #00BFFF;
   border: 0px #000 solid;

}
#photo
{
   border: 1px #A9A9A9 solid;
   background-color: #00BFFF;
   color: #fff;
   font-family:Arial;
   font-size: 20px;
}
    </style>
                        <a title="par home page" href="http://localhost/PROJ/par_welcome.php" class="btn btn-warning">par homepage</a> <br><br>
                            <table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0" class="table table-bordered">     
            <tr><td><form enctype="multipart/form-data"  action="" id="wb_Form1" name="form" method="post">     
                    <input type="file" name="photo" id="photo" accept="application/pdf"  required="required"></td>



                    <td><input type="submit" class="btn btn-danger" value="SUBMIT" name="submit">
            </form> <strong>SUBMIT HERE</strong></tr></td></table>
                 <div class="col-md-18">
    <div class="container-fluid" style="margin-top:0px;">
   <div class = "row">
        <div class="panel panel-default">
            <div class="panel-body">
                <div class="table-responsive">


                        <form method="post" action="delete.php" >
                     <table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0" class="table table-condensed" id="example">

                            <thead>

                                <tr>

                                    <th>ID</th>
                                    <th>FILE NAME</th>
                                   <th>Date</th>
                                    <th>username</th>

                    <th>Download</th>   
                        <th>view</th>


                                </tr>
                            </thead>
                            <tbody>

                        <?php 
                            $query=mysqli_query($conn, "select * from `upload` left join `par` on par.par_id=upload.par_id where par.par_id= '".$_SESSION['par_id']."' ORDER BY id DESC ");

                               // $query=mysqli_query($conn, "select * from `upload` left join `par` on par.par_id=upload.par_id where p_username = '".$_SESSION['par_id']."' ORDER BY id DESC ");
                                if($query === false){
    throw new Exception(mysql_error($conn));
}
                            while($row=mysqli_fetch_array($query)){
                            $id=$row['id'];
                            $name=$row['name'];
                            $date=$row['date'];
                            $username = $row['p_username'];
                            ?>
                                        <tr>

                                         <td><?php echo $row['id'] ?></td>
                                         <td><?php echo $row['name'] ?></td>
                                         <td><?php echo $row['date'] ?></td>
                                             <td> <?php echo $row['p_username'] ?></td>
    <td>
            <!--    <a href="download.php?filename=<?php // echo $name;?>" title="click to download">VIEW <!--<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-paperclip" style="font-size:20px; color:blue"></span> -->
                <!--    </a> --> 
                 <input type="button" value="Open PDF" onclick = "openPdf()"/>
     </td>
                 <td>
                   <iframe id="myFrame" style="display:none" width="600" height="300"></iframe>
                 </td>  




                                </tr>

                                  <?php }
                                ?>
                            </tbody>
                        </table>
                           </div>

</form>
                                                        <!--*******************************************-->
                                                        <script>
                                                        function openPdf()
                                        {
                                        var omyFrame = document.getElementById("myFrame");
                                        omyFrame.style.display="block";
                                        omyFrame.src = "PRICE LIST.pdf";
                                        }
                                                        </script>
                                                        <!--**************************************-->
      </div>
        </div>
        </div>
    </div>



</body>
</html>
```

---

download.php

```
    <?php
function output_file($file, $name, $mime_type='')
{
//if(!is_readable($file)) die('<script type="text/javascript">alert("File not found!");location.replace("index.php")
    if(!is_readable($file)) die('<script type="text/javascript">alert("File not found!");location.replace("par_upload.php")
    </script>');

$size = filesize($file);
$name = rawurldecode($name);
$known_mime_types=array(
"pdf" => "application/pdf",
"txt" => "text/plain",
"html" => "text/html",
"htm" => "text/html",
"exe" => "application/octet-stream",
"zip" => "application/zip",
"doc" => "application/msword",
"xls" => "application/vnd.ms-excel",
"ppt" => "application/vnd.ms-powerpoint",
"gif" => "image/gif",
"png" => "image/png",
"jpeg"=> "image/jpg",
"jpg" => "image/jpg",
"php" => "text/plain"
);
if($mime_type==''){
$file_extension = strtolower(substr(strrchr($file,"."),1));
if(array_key_exists($file_extension, $known_mime_types)){
$mime_type=$known_mime_types[$file_extension];
} else {
$mime_type="application/force-download";
};
};

@ob_end_clean();


if(ini_get('zlib.output_compression'))
ini_set('zlib.output_compression', 'Off');



   // header('Content-Type: ' . $mime_type);
    header('Content-type: application/pdf');

header('Content-Disposition: inline; filename="'.$name.'"');
//header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="'.$name.'"');


header("Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary");
header('Accept-Ranges: bytes');
header("Cache-control: private");
header('Pragma: private');
header("Expires: Mon, 26 Jul 2017 05:00:00 GMT");
if(isset($_SERVER['HTTP_RANGE']))
{
list($a, $range) = explode("=",$_SERVER['HTTP_RANGE'],2);
list($range) = explode(",",$range,2);
list($range, $range_end) = explode("-", $range);
$range=intval($range);
if(!$range_end) {
$range_end=$size-1;
} else {
$range_end=intval($range_end);
}
$new_length = $range_end-$range+1;
header("HTTP/1.1 206 Partial Content");
header("Content-Length: $new_length");
header("Content-Range: bytes $range-$range_end/$size");
} else {
$new_length=$size;
header("Content-Length: ".$size);
}
$chunksize = 1*(1024*1024);
$bytes_send = 0;
if ($file = fopen($file, 'r'))
{
if(isset($_SERVER['HTTP_RANGE']))
fseek($file, $range);

while(!feof($file) &&
(!connection_aborted()) &&
($bytes_send<$new_length)
)
{
$buffer = fread($file, $chunksize);
print($buffer);
flush();
$bytes_send += strlen($buffer);
}
fclose($file);
} else

die('Error - cannot open file.');
die();
}
set_time_limit(0);
$file_path='par_files/'.$_REQUEST['filename'];
output_file($file_path, ''.$_REQUEST['filename'].'', 'text/plain');
?>
```

Comment: Where is this javascript, before or after the HTML, probably it's running before the element is created.  ie.  `ready()`

Comment: @ArtisticPhoenix i didnt include the complete code here

Comment: Well, that's fine, but you apparently don't have enough of the essential things or I wouldn't have asked.  When debugging we must consider the way it could fail.  One way is if the DOM is not ready when the JavaScript runs.

Comment: How is the file stored? Binary data in database or just a URL pointing to a file location?

Comment: `omyFrame.src = "PRICE LIST.pdf";` suggests it's a file, I would avoid the space if it was me, as that can cause issues in some cases.

Comment: i share the whole code

Comment: @ArtisticPhoenix pls read the question again i do not want the iframe to open a specific file

Comment: You do want a specific file, as you certainly don't want a random file.  But that's besides the point, as I said `spaces` can be a url killer as can capitalization  You may want one from the DB in which case you'll have to embed that information somewhere, like in the button.

Comment: @ArtisticPhoenix check the img....now suppose if i upload a file named abc.pdf i can`t have another code to display abc.pdf so i need to specify it to a variable

Comment: @Phil i store the file in the pc and only specify the name in the db

Comment: `i can't have another code to display abc.pdf ` why not, you can reload the page, you can use AJAX, we have the technology for this.

Comment: @ArtisticPhoenix the scenario is such dont u know how to do it how i require

Comment: `SOMEONE PLS HELP`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try making a full URL out of the src path, and don't include any spaces in the path. So, something like this:

```
omyFrame.src = "http://example.com/pdfs/PRICE%20LIST.pdf";
```

I've just been playing around with manipulating an iframe this way, and it seems to work.

I know you said you are getting these PDFs from a DB, that you aren't trying to load a specific file, but for this to work with an iframe it would be best if your server would serve up the contents of each PDF from a specific URL.

---

OK, so, based on your comments below, you could use a link like this:

```
<a href="javascript:void(0)"
  onclick="openPdf('download.php?filename=<?php echo $name;?>')"
  title="click to download">VIEW <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-paperclip"
  style="font-size:20px; color:blue"></span>
</a>
```

Then modify `openPdf()` like this:

```
function openPdf(src)
{
  var omyFrame = document.getElementById("myFrame");
  omyFrame.style.display="block";
  omyFrame.src = src;
}
```

Comment: this is not what i want check the img

Comment: See my extended response above. I am still talking about getting the PDFs from the DB, just assuming you can serve up those PDFs from a particular URL.

Comment: i did not understand what u are trying to convey....earlier i made this as i click open pdf button thee pdf would open it in a new webpage but i didnt like that and want to display it in the  same webpage that was the reason why i made an iframe....but cant understand how to do the exact same thing inside it

Comment: If you've got a URL that can be used to open one of these PDFs in a new web page, then you should be able to set the `src` of your `iframe` to that same URL. What happens if you try to do that?

Comment: `<a href="download.php?filename=<?php  echo $name;?>" title="click to download">VIEW  
       </a> ` **this is what i used earlier**

Comment: i copied the exact same code u posted above and tried it....i got some msg

Comment: `If you've got a URL that can be used to open one of these PDFs in a new web page, then you should be able to set the src of your iframe to that same URL. What happens if you try to do that? ` thats what i cant understand how to do

Comment: I just added more to my answer above (too much formatting needed to answer in one of these comments).

Comment: i tried what u said but a blank  iframe is displayed when i click the VIEW....however i added this link s u said but i can only open PRICE LIST.pdf not any other file how to do it.... `http://localhost/PROJ/FILE%20MANAGER/download.php?filename=PRICE%20LIST.pdf`

Comment: i added the code of download.php  pls check it as well and pls try helping me

Comment: If you were able to open all of your PDFs in a separate window before using your original link, you've got to be pretty close now to being able to open them in an iframe, because it's just a matter of getting that same URL that each new window had opened with stuffed into the src attribute of your iframe. It's too bad it's so hard to debug something like this remotely.

Comment: i know bro i`m only inches away and can understand how difficult it would be debug a code remotely  i have shared the whole code required to do it in a new webpage but to display it inside an iframe it sucks!!! if possible pls try to to find a possible solution

Comment: **THANKS A LOT BRO THE ABOVE CODE WORKS I THINK I MISSED SOMETHING EARLIER**

Comment: Good to hear. Yay!